# Will my API key be exposed to network administrators if I use it

Tags: security

I'm new to using APIs and I'm concerned about exposing it on a public network. I am at my public library, connected to their public WiFi, and using Rstudio. I want to get some U.S. census data via the Census API [here](https://api.census.gov/data.html). I already have an API key.

My question is: if I enter the key and run my script to acquire the data I need on my own personal computer, is my API key exposed to the network administrators?

Comment: You should update your post with the API URL. Use HTTPS and you're probably fine. Ensure the latest protocols and strong ciphers are being used. ssllabs.com offers client and server testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the connection to the Census API is encrypted (e.g. via HTTPS) then no, network administrators can't see the contents of the request. They **can** see which hostname you're connecting to, but nothing else. Only someone on your own PC and someone on the remote Census API server can read the clear-text request.

If the connection is **not** encrypted, then any data transferred is essentially readable by anyone anywhere along the link.